# Javascript image upload, need description embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the main thing that I am trying to do is get this simple image uploader to also allow the user to enter and store a description along with the image that is uploaded. Also some way to clear the images stored once they are in the preview.

What I currently have is

```
  <html>
<body>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function main()
{
    var inputFileToLoad = document.createElement("input");
    inputFileToLoad.type = "file";
    inputFileToLoad.id = "inputFileToLoad";
    document.body.appendChild(inputFileToLoad);

    var buttonLoadFile = document.createElement("button");
    buttonLoadFile.onclick = loadImageFileAsURL;
    buttonLoadFile.textContent = "Load Selected File";
    document.body.appendChild(buttonLoadFile);
}

function loadImageFileAsURL()
{
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0)
    {
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

        if (fileToLoad.type.match("image.*"))
        {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
            {
                var imageLoaded = document.createElement("img");
                imageLoaded.src = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                document.body.appendChild(imageLoaded);
            };
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }
    }
}

main();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To get a description just create another input element within the form. Your code is not showing how you actually upload the image. So I guess it's a form with a POST action?

To clear the image, just add a button that removes the "img" element. For ease of use, just make the "imageLoaded" global and then remove that from the DOM when pressing that button.